# Can we see kdump log without crashing kernel?

Tags: linux, kernel

I am studying system call in kernel. while doing this I can get code flow after kernel crash using crash utility. Is there any way to see kernel memory dump without crashing kernel ?

Answer (score -1):

to get the kernel log, you can use `dmesg` command and redirect the output to analyze it. Example:

```
sudo dmesg > output.txt
```

for sysm call in kernel there are some tools that can help you, like `ftarce` [ftrace](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/trace/ftrace.txt) or systemtap.

If you know the function name that you should to trace, you can code a little kernel module using [kprobe and jprobe](http://opensourceforu.efytimes.com/2011/04/kernel-debugging-using-kprobe-and-jprobe/).